# Android app closes due because of button.setOnClickListener(this)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm going through a tutorial that's teaching me about Android App development. I've been going through it all just fine but for some reason when I run this activity the app closes and says that it has stopped working. As far as I can tell I have copied the person's code correctly, but his works.
I found that the problem is with the line inside onCreate that says `tryCmd.setOnClickListener(this);`

If I comment out that single line, the activity works fine(but just doesn't do anything when I click the button, obviously). The app works fine with the togglebutton's onClickListener statement. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Here is all the code from my activity.java:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Text extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText input;
    Button tryCmd;
    ToggleButton passTog;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        //Call the method to assign variables to the elements.
        assignVariables(); 
        //Initialize the button and ToggleButton to work with the onClick method.
        passTog.setOnClickListener(this);
        tryCmd.setOnClickListener(this);        

    }

    private void assignVariables() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        Button tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
        passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bResults:
            String check = input.getText().toString();
            if (check.contentEquals("left")){
                display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            }else if(check.contentEquals("center")){
                display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }else if(check.contentEquals("right")){
                display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }else if(check.contentEquals("blue")){
                display.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else if(check.contains("WTF")){
                Random crazy = new Random();
                display.setText("WTF!?!?");
                display.setTextSize(crazy.nextInt(75));
                display.setTextColor(Color.rgb(crazy.nextInt(255), crazy.nextInt(255), crazy.nextInt(255)));
                switch(crazy.nextInt(3)){
                case 0:
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);                     
                    break;
                case 2:
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);                      
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                display.setText("invalid");
                display.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }

            //Clear the input box if it doesn't contain WTF.
            if(!check.contains("WTF")){
                input.setText("");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.tbPassword:
            if (passTog.isChecked()){
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else{
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Logcat/Error stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Problem with this line..

```
Button tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

You Are creating local Variable and Assigning value to new local Variable... So the global variable is still **NULL**..

So Remove that line from **assignVariables()** function..

Try This code...

```
private void assignVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do so but it wouldn't let me for 5 minutes. It is done now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are initialize `tryCmd`  as local variable. 
and set onClickListner onglobal variable `tryCmd`

remove **Button** from this line

```
Button tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

and change it

```
tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

you define `tryCmd` as local variable so it detect only in `assignVariables()` method.you should change it to global variable.(as you define but not use)

```
private void assignVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    Button tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);//error in this line you define it as local variable delete Button before it
    passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}
```

edited:

```
private void assignVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    tryCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}
```